# hadoop fs -du gives two data columns

Tags: unix, hadoop, hadoop2

I ran the following command on my test hadoop instance :

```
hadoop fs -du /test/data/

51179082   153537246   /test/data/9875/2016/02/03
46949272   140847816   /test/data/9875/2016/02/04
```

I understand `du` gives the size of files and directories, but for `hadoop fs -du` it is giving two sizes. Can some one help me understand what are these?

Comment: its is similar to the unix du , since you have 2 folders , it showed the folder specific size

Comment: I dont think so, because i now have three folders and it is giving 2 columns for each of those

Answer (score 35, accepted):

One column is size of the file and the other column is size of the file after replication.

Comment: which is which?

Comment: @sheldonkreger The first is the *size* and the second is the *space consumed*, i.e. the post-replication size. So a replication of 3 would cause three times the size to be consumed in space.

Comment: I have a 1 node cluster. The cluster complains of under-replicated blocks. However the 2nd value shows nearly 3x of the 1st value!